# Do we want slang / short forms like "TL;DR" in questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Scanning unanswered question I found [Can't download/export a large Google Docs document as PDF (what are the limits on Google Drive?)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88258/cant-download-export-a-large-google-docs-document-as-pdf-what-are-the-limits-o). It uses `TL;DR` as a heading.

I don't have problems with the use of short words and slang or jargon in comments. I know that some are very popular but I don't think that they should be used as a heading in a question nor an answer.

At this time there are <s>8</s> [5 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22TL%3BDR%22+is%3Aquestion) that use `TL;DR`.

Is it acceptable to replace this with another form like "Summary", "Overview" or "Brief description"?

## References

[What is a “TL;DR version”? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70813/what-is-a-tldr-version)

Answer (score 4):

In the case of *tl;dr*, I think it's reasonably well-understood online. I don't know that we need to replace its use.

Other, more esoteric, abbreviations should be expanded and/or replaced with standard English phrases.